# Mirror Raid to Single Harddisk ACPI BIOS in the system is not fully compliant with the ACPI

Tags: linux, security, raid, bios

My server used to be setup as a Mirror which means the 2nd harddisk would take the image of 1st harddisk. In anycase 1st harddisk is dead, 2nd harddisk would take over.

It wasn't setup by me & Now i'm trying to run Windows 7 on a SINGLE harddisk only but it's giving me as titled error.

I tried changing from AHCI to IDE , Enable Legacy support, disable the security I still cant get it to install my Windows 7.

I also check this utility tool for the "raid" and couldn't find any option i can toggle to alternative.

I tried this Windows 7 Disk on a laptop and it installs fine which is why i'm thinking the issue is with my BIOS.

ANY ANY kind of advice would be greatly appreciated! Fairly Urgent , Kinda got no choice but to post here.

Hope you understand! THanks!

Comment: Just what sort of "server" is this?

Comment: Hmm A server with 2 harddisk slot?

Comment: Can you be any more vague?

Comment: It's a normal computer. My mistake, just that it was placed in a server case.

Comment: What is a "single hard disk acpi bios"?